# Will Allah accept my prayers during the fasting days to make up for masturbating?

Tags: dua, masturbation, kaffarah

I am 15 year old boy, and I have an addiction that is very hard for me to stop.  The addiction I have is one of many people, and it is masturbation.

I understand that there is a toll of feeding people every day for 60 days or fasting 60 days straight. I come from a family that needs social assistance with money.  I have no job and right now no money.  I have done this sin about 10 times causing me to break my fast.  In this month, I want to know if Allah will accept my prayer and duas during the days I having fasted and if I am not able to pay my toll, will my fast be accepted next year?  Will I go to hell for this?

Answer (score 1):

As Salaam Alaykum....
    Several times in the Quran, the story of the prophet Adam (as) is mentioned. Do you remember? 
 It's where our enemy promises to distract us from the path of ALLAH(swt). Between the seven times the story comes up, it is clear that the plan of shaytan is to stand in the way of our uprightness in any way he can.

As a young man in the deen, you are our hope -it is up to you and your generation to continue faithfully what has been in place for 1,400 plus years..... Things done as closely as possible as our beloved prophet (saws) did  for the pleasure of ALLAH (swt).

With all that being said, my love, it seems that you are a little bit distracted. Ramadan is a time of work. It is a time of giving. It is a time of dhikr. What does that mean to a youth like yourself? You should find ways to make your life and the life of the ummat better, for the pleasure of ALLAH (swt).

Every precious moment you are given should be spent in giving your energy to the cause.

1. Read. Read Seerah of the Nabi. See how those Noble Men (as) lived and try to be more like them.
2. Help your little brothers /sisters learn to read.
3. Clean up your yard and start a food garden.

4.make every prayer on time in the masjid. Make your sunnahs. Try to read a hisb of Quran after you pray.

5.ask your parents if they need anything done around the house. Do it the best you can with an open heart.

6. Offer (volunteer)to work at the masjid. You would be surprised at how many things need to be done each night for Iftar.
7. Develop your salat. Research. What are the different types of fard, sunnah, and nawafil prayers?

One purpose of Ramadan is to develop good habits that you keep and maintain after Ramadan. Develop habits that would make your RABB proud of you. And do them daily.

Soon, you will be an adult and you will have a wife. But for now, you must truly understand that you have a responsibility in the ummat. If you are distracted by the enemy, you will not be able to work for the pleasure of ALLAH (swt). HE wants you to be happy, and HE understands your nature better than anyone-HE created us. :)

Until the third half of Ramadan, the time between Isha and Suhoor/Fajr is your own to spend as you like. BUT...... You could make Taraweh prayer at the masjid, and tahajjud and Shafi Witr after you get some sleep.

You must know that you are loved. You must also know that a grateful person is appreciative, and they show appreciation with good works-deeds. These are the only things you can take with you to your grave.

Comment: 8 . Stay in Company of Good Muslim Friends

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to seek forgiveness from Allah (SWT) for what you have done. You have not only committed an act that's haram but also violated the sanctity of a holy month-- the month of Ramadan.

Second, masturbation does break your fast if you ejaculate as a result, which is I guess the case in this case. And one shouldn't eat or drink for the rest of the day after masturbation because of the sanctity of the holy month of Ramadan.

As for its expiation, based on my understanding there's no expiation but simply making up for the days you have masturbated in. So in your case you have to make up for 10 days and seek plenty of forgiveness from Allah (SWT). Here's an excerpt from [islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/38074) that lists a few scholars who are of the same opinion.

> Shaykh Ibn Baaz said:
>
> Masturbation during the day in Ramadaan invalidates the fast if it is done deliberately and semen is emitted as a result. The person must make up the day if that was an obligatory fast, and he must repent to Allaah, because masturbation is not permissible whether one is fasting or not. It is the action which people call the “secret habit”.
>
> Fataawa al-Shaykh Ibn Baaz, 15/267
>
> Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on him) said:
>
> If a fasting person masturbates and ejaculates, this breaks his fast, and he has to make up the fast of the day on which he masturbated, but he does not have to offer any expiation, because the expiation is only required of one who has intercourse. And he has to repent from what he did.
>
> Fataawa Arkaan al-Islam, p. 478

As for next year, you should definitely fast and ask Allah to accept yours and ours prayers and fasting.

Allah is the Most Merciful and nobody knows who will go to hell or heaven except Allah (SWT). That's something that will be decided on the day of judgement. We as humans have to do our best. Worship Him and follow His commandment. We also have to ask Him to accept our prayers and worship on a daily basis.

It's also better to consult a local mufti to get a stronger opinion on your situation. I am not an Alim or Mufti and provided the information based on my research from various sources.

Allah (SWT) knows best.